# conditional-formatting: alternating colors for headline --> color also cells in between the start and stop cellvalue

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'v attached a screenshot to show what I'd like to ask for. Since I am obviously having issues to word it properly.
I got this sheet to track project hours. It's a template also for future projects. So I built it with a dynamic start month and year. 
In order to avoid the tedious formatting work in future I've set up several conditional formattings.

I now please need an idea how to change the color alternating, based on the color of the previous month. In the screenshot you see June and July have different cell colors, which I obv did manually; thats what I'd like to solve dynamically

I can distinguish where the start and the stop of one month is by filling each cell of the headline with the value based on the date. I though I could simply hide it then when formatting the textcolor same with the bg color. Still same problem: how do I check which color to use?!

I think I totally lost track - anyone help please? :)

Thanks & BR

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAxq9.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read at least the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Is there a screenshot missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With real dates in Row2 (formatted `mmm` if you wish), fill as much of Row2 as relevant with one 'standard' fill colour, select Row2, clear any CF from it and then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ISEVEN(MONTH(A2))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select a different Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: great, thanks for your input. that worked nicely. thanks again !